# Get first comment link on the post itself

Tags: posts, php, query, comments

I have this function and a link to a post:

```
<?php
foreach ($results as $id) {
  $post = &get_post( $id->ID );
  setup_postdata($post);

  <li><a <?php href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

</li>
  <?php
} ?>
```

What I want to do is this: if there is a comment posted **today**, than show me the link to the first comment that has been posted. So for example: if there are 4 comments made today, I want the link to the first comment instead of the permalink just like now.

I tried using this:
    `<a <?php href="<?php the_permalink(get_comments->$post_id) ?>">postname</a>` and variations of this like `comment_post_ID`, but I could not get it to work. What am I doing wrong and what should I do? Please, help me...

Comment: @s_ha_dum, why did you remove your answer? I thought we were close.

Answer (score 0):

you can get comment link by wp function

```
$args = array(
    'number' => '1',
    'post_id' => your_post_id, // use post_id, not post_ID
);
$comments = get_comments($args);

    <a href="<?php echo get_comment_link( $comments->comment_ID ); ?>">postname</a>
```

Comment: Oeh, almost there... It does this: `http://sitename/post-name/comment-page-/#comment-` , so it ends with the stripe, no number or whatsoever.... And btw: how do I get it for TODAY's posts only?

Comment: no option to filter by date, you need to check it with `$comments->comment_date`  or `$comments->comment_date_gmt`

Comment: But why is your code not working? I can't get a number?

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`WP_Comment_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Comment_Query).

```
function comment_where_wpse_108654($clauses) {
  $clauses['where'] .= ' AND DATE(comment_date) = "'.date('Y-m-d').'"';
  remove_filter('comments_clauses','comment_where_wpse_108654');
  return $clauses;
}
add_filter('comments_clauses','comment_where_wpse_108654');

$args = array(
  'post_id' => $post->ID,
  'number' => 1,
  'orderby' => 'comment_date',
  'order' => 'desc'
);
$comment_qry = new WP_Comment_Query;
$comment = $comment_qry->query( $args );
```

That assumes that `$post->ID` is correct.

Now if the theme is building comment IDs right then `echo get_permalink().'/#comment-'.$comment[0]->comment_ID;` should be a link to your comment.

Edit: You seem to be confused how to make this work with multiple posts/comments.

```
function comment_where_wpse_108654($clauses) {
  $clauses['where'] .= ' AND DATE(comment_date) = "'.date('Y-m-d').'"';
  return $clauses;
}
add_filter('comments_clauses','comment_where_wpse_108654');

foreach ($results as $id) {

  $args = array(
    'post_id' => $id->ID, // your $id->ID should work just as well
    'number' => 1,
    'orderby' => 'comment_date',
    'order' => 'desc'
  );

  $comment_qry = new WP_Comment_Query;
  $comment = $comment_qry->query( $args );

  if (!empty($comment[0])) { ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink().'/#comment-'.$comment[0]->comment_ID; ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li><?php
  }
}
remove_filter('comments_clauses','comment_where_wpse_108654');
```

Comment: So the only thing I have to do is use `<?php echo comment_where_wpse_108564(); ?>` ? I will test it, thanks. You will here from me.

Comment: No. The filter is for the query that follows. `var_dump($comment)` and you will see an array of comment objects-- just one in this case. You'd then `echo` whatever parts you want. For example, `echo $comment[0]->comment_content;`

Comment: I don't get it brother. I have pasted your code in to `functions.php`, I guess that's fine. Than I echoed the thing I said, that showed me the text `array` indeed, but now, I don't know what to do? Don't I just have to put an anchor and than the href with your `echo $comment[0]->comment_content;`? I don't get it. I mean it has to do something with the anchor I already have in my first post?

Comment: FYI: `echo $comment[0]->comment_content;` gives me just 1 comment. I want per post to get it a link... That's why I am asking you: don't I have to put this in the `foreach` in the anchor or list?

Comment: Almost, almost! It is getting the comment of the first-post indeed, which is very very nice, but it does that for the MOST RECENT POST and not per post.... Is there a way that we can make the `comment[0] more generic, so that it does per post's new comment?

Comment: Would love an answer on this one as well...

Comment: @s_ha_dum can you help?

Comment: Run at each iteration of your Loop (use your `$id` variable), that _would_ give you the link to the first comment of each post. Admittedly, that isn't very efficient. There might be other ways to do it though but there is not much context to the code you posted.

Comment: Hmm, using the $id instead of what? I tried this `echo get_permalink().'/#comment-'.$comment[$id]->comment_ID;` and `echo get_permalink().'/#comment-'.$comment[0]->$id;` but both did not work. Can you help me, please? That's the only code I have btw, the whole foreach is just so small.

Comment: @user1627363 : see the edit

Comment: Thanks, but it says: ` Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in`. So now, I just paste your second code in to functions.php and that's it?

Comment: I am assuming that `$results` is set correctly. That part is missing from your code, so I have assumed it to work. There is no other `foreach` that could be causing trouble.

Comment: Yes, results is working correctly. No problems with it at all. This is very weird and frustrating.

Comment: No one who can help?